# Clear cart Woocommerce when close browser

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i try to clean the cart when the browser is close. In this time i have the next code, it works whe you go to main page

```
/*empty cart if user come to homepage*/
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
global $woocommerce;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') { 
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
}
}
```

how to change this code when browser is close clean the cart

Comment: There's no way to handle this directly, but you could adjust the session settings such that the session cookie is removed on closing the browser

Comment: do yo know how can removed cookies cart when the user close the browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 
'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );

function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {

global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
```

}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**